# How to write nginx config file to allow 3 languages switching.

Tags: nginx, config, modx, winginx

From this [example](https://gist.github.com/netProphET/8e29c06cee9ab8b8fab2), it explains the way to write nginx config to switch the language between DE and EN. using Modx as CMS. However, I have 3 languages which are EN/DA/TH. Please guide me to the right approach of writing nginx config to change between 3 languages. (Please note, EN is the default)
The following is the nginx config that allows only 2 languages switching.

```
set $lang de;
# choose the language that appears first in the accept_language header
if ($http_accept_language ~* "(de|en)") {
  set $lang $1;
}
location ~ ^/$ {
rewrite ^ $lang/ redirect;
}

location ~ ^/(de|en) {
# redirect favicon.ico and assets/* requests to site root
rewrite ^/(de|en)/(favicon.ico|assets.*)$ /$2 redirect;
# main Babel rewrite
rewrite ^/(de|en)/(.*)$ /?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 break;
# MODX rewrite
try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite;
}
```

Comment: did you try replacing `(de|en)` with `(en|da|th)`?

Comment: Yes I did. But it seems doesn't work. It redirects to 'EN' even the url has da or th.

Comment: What is in `@modx-rewrite` ?

Comment: The example at https://gist.github.com/netProphET/8e29c06cee9ab8b8fab2 is specific to MODX Cloud. Aside from the nginx config, it will also require changing the plugin to accept the different cultureKeys.